# How to start Xamarin-Android-Player from command line?

Tags: bash, android-emulator, xamarin

Is there any possibility to run a Xamarin Android Player device from command line on a Mac?

I'm writing automated UI-tests and want to start them with a bash-script. For Android I have to start the emulator first, and as the standard Android emulator is unacceptably slow, I need to use XAP.

Basically I am searching for a command similar to the "normal" command:

```
./emulator -avd NameOfYourEmulator -partition-size 512
```

for Xamarin Android Player.
The command above does not work because the XAP-devices are not saved like the regular AVDs but as .vdi-files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the command by browsing through the open processes on my Mac (ps -f -x from command line). It is quite simple:

```
/path/to/xap/executable --name "Device Name"
```

For me this was:

```
/Applications/Xamarin\ Android\ Player.app/Contents/Helpers/Xamarin\ Android\ Player.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin\ Android\ Player --name "Nexus 5 (KitKat)"
```

(backslashes needed to escape spaces)

The problem that occurs now is that the device is locked, but that is a different story.

**Edit:**

If someone is interested in how to unlock the phone from command line, its:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the current version of Xamarin Android Player. Player starts, but it does not start the device identified by the name parameter. Any ideas ?